# Add TensorFlow and Numpy libraries to osgeo/gdal docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, gdal

I'm using Docker to build and run my projects.

I need to use `gdal` library, but using `pip install gdal` I have lots of error, so I tried to download from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/gdal/docker the GDAL docker images.

Now I would like to run my .py file but I have to import also TensorFlow and Numpy and other libraries. GDAL docker image, as I expected, doesn't come with other libraries.

Is there a way to build a new image from GDAL docker image and include other libraries?
I tried to make something similar with Nvidia TF docker image and it works (Dockerfile down below) without gdal library installed, but if I change `FROM osgeo/gdal` (name of GDAL image) I have an error `pip can't be find`.

```
#Dockerfile 
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:19.12-tf2-py3
WORKDIR /work
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
FROM osgeo/gdal
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
WORKDIR /work
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After that, you can install TF via requirements.txt file and you are done!